# cross browser solution for listening to requests and capturing screenshots

Tags: browser, cross-browser, greasemonkey, bookmarklet

I need to create a plugin/extension/bookmarklet/greasemonkey script that allows the user to capture arbitrary requests and send them back to a web service with some tags. For example, the user would get to a page and click "capture", and they would be presented with a dialog asking them for some tags and/or a description and then the current window location would be sent off to a web service. Here's the catch:

1. The user should also be able to view async requests and 'capture' them the same way they can capture the window location
2. The user should be able to capture a screenshot of their current page and send that back through the web service

Given these last two complications I am leaning towards a browser plugin as the solution (probably firefox, since low-level http stuff seems to be better supported than in chrome), but I am wondering if anyone has an idea for a more cross-browser-y solution, and or if there is something out there that might provide a good API for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be a cross-browser solution that allows capturing all requests. For Firefox you would implement the [nsIContentPolicy interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIContentPolicy) and register your component in the `content-policy` category. For Chrome you would need the [experimental webRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html) (the `beforeload` event in WebKit browsers will sort of do the same thing but it won't capture everything, it also has [severe side-effects](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45586)).

As to webpage screenshots, this is possible in Firefox extensions by using the HTML `<canvas>` tag and calling [drawWindow method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#Rendering_Web_Content_Into_A_Canvas). You can then export the data via `canvas.toDataURL()`. <del>I am not aware of any alternatives for WebKit browsers.</del> [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) allows doing the same thing in Chrome.

Comment: I found this http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab method which supposedly offers support for screen capture.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer to reflect this possibility.